# why the code this point to window object?

Tags: javascript, arguments, this

my code is:

```
var length = 20;
function fn(){
    console.log(this.length);
}

var o = {
    length:10,
    e:function (fn){
       fn();
       arguments[0]();
    }
}

o.e(fn);
```

the output is `20,1`,who can tell me why?

Comment: Do some reading on [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) and [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)

Comment: @muistooshort you're saying of `fn()` and `arguments[0]()`, one calls `call` and the other calls `apply`?

Comment: In the first call where you get 20 `this === window`, in the second `this===arguments`. Change console.log to `console.log(this.length,this);` and the call to `o.e(fn,'test');` and you see that you get the arguments array.

Comment: @dbaseman: Those were more about doing `fn()` with an explicit `this`. The `arguments[0]()` one behaves as it does because there is a hidden dot so it is sort of like saying `arguments.0()` (if the latter was valid JavaScript of course).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When the `this` keyword occurs inside a function, its value depends on **how the function is called**.

In your case, `fn()` is called without providing the a this value, so the default value is `window`.
With `arguments[0]()`, the context is the `arguments` object, whose length is `1`.

The point is it does not matter **where the function is called**, but it matters **how the function is called**.

```
var length = 20;
function fn(){
    console.log(this.length);
}

var o = {
    length:10,
    e:function (fn){
       fn(); // this will be the window.
       arguments[0](); // this will be arguments object.
    }
}

o.e(fn);
```

Further more, if you want `this` to be the object `o`, you could use `call` or `apply`, or `bind` an object first.

```
var length = 20;
function fn(){
    console.log(this.length);
}

var o = {
    length:10,
    e:function (fn){
       var fn2 = fn.bind(this);
       fn.call(this); // this in fn will be the object o.
       fn.apply(this); // this in fn will be the object o.
       fn2(); // this also will be the object o.
    }
}

o.e(fn);
```

Comment: `this` is not context, it is a component of an execution context (or lexical environment in ES5). You should have written `fn() is called without providing a this value`. Calling `this` context is just confusing.

Comment: Oh, and if the code was in strict mode, then a Type error would be thrown as it will not set `this` to `window` if a value isn't provided (it will be undefined).

Comment: @RobG Yes, in strict mode, this will be undefined when do `fn();`

Answer (score 2):

Let's expand your code a little bit:

```
var length = 20;
function fn() {
    console.log(this, this.length);
}

var o = {
    length: 10,
    e: function(fn) {
        fn();
        fn.call(this);
        arguments[0]();
    }
}

o.e(fn);​
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/Ckf2b/

Now we can see what `this` is (and thus where `this.length` comes from) when `fn` is called. This gives me the following output:

```
DOMWindow 0
Object 10
[function fn() { console.log(this, this.length); }] 1
```

We also have three ways of calling the function `fn`:

1. `fn()`: just call it like any old function.
2. `fn.call(this)`: Use [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) to force a specific context (AKA `this`).
3. `arguments[0]()`: Call `fn` through the `arguments` object.

When you say `fn()`, there is no explicit value of `this` anywhere in sight so, in a browser, you get `window` as your `this`. The global `window` happens to have a [`length` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.length):

> Returns the number of frames (either frame or iframe elements) in the window.

That's where the zero (in my output) comes from, your `window.length` may be different.

We call `e` as `o.e(fn)` so `this` inside `e` is `o`, that's what `o.e(...)` means (barring bound functions and related complexities). So the `this` in `fn.call(this)` is `o` and that makes `fn.call(this)` the same (more or less) as `o.fn = fn; o.fn()` and we get `o` and `10` in the console. Notice that dot showing up again?

> `fn.call(o)` is like `o.fn = fn; o.fn()`

The third one, `arguments[0]()`, contains a hidden dot as `p = 'm'; o[p]` is (more or less) the same as `o.m` so `arguments[0]()` is like `fn = arguments[0]; arguments.fn = fn; arguments.fn()`.