# how can I print the text of 'this' list item by backbone.js?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-views

I'm new at Backbone.js.And I hava some problem at this keyworks.I hava a Backbone view blow:

```
 var print = Backbone.View.extend({
    el : $('ul li.newItem'),  
    events : { 'click li.newItem':'printText'},
    initialize:function(){ 
      _.bind(printText,this);  // does 'this' refer to the li.newItem ?
      alert(1233); // init does't work.
    },
    printText : function(){
      //I wanna print the hello world text each list item when clicked.
    }
  });

 var print = new print();
```

Here is my demo : http://jsbin.com/evoqef/3/edit

Comment: Try this http://jsbin.com/evoqef/9/

Comment: Are you sure?nothing change...

Comment: i don't understand what is the problem you are facing. The jsbin prints the hello world correctly right ? also do `var printF = new print();` because print is already defined

Comment: when i click the list,i want to alert the li's text.

Comment: Try this http://jsbin.com/evoqef/11/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two problems that are keeping your `initialize` from working:

1. There is no `printText` in scope.
2. [`_.bind`](http://underscorejs.org/#bind) and [`_.bindAll`](http://underscorejs.org/#bindAll) behave differently.

The first is easy to fix, you want to use `this.printText`, not just `printText`.

`_.bind` binds a single function to a `this` and *returns* that bound function; `_.bindAll`, on the other hand, binds several named functions to a `this` and leaves the bound functions attached to the specified `this`. So, doing this:

```
_.bind(printText, this);
```

doesn't do anything useful as you're throwing away the bound function. You'd want to do this:

```
this.printText = _.bind(this.printText, this);
```

Or more commonly in Backbone apps, you'd use `_.bindAll`:

```
_.bindAll(this, 'printText');
```

Now you have a functioning `initialize` and you'll have the right `this` inside `printText` and we can move on to fixing `printText`. I think you want to extract the text from the `<li>` that was clicked; you can do this like this:

```
printText: function(ev) {
    console.log($(ev.target).text());
}
```

But that still doesn't work and we're left to wondering what's going on here. Well, Backbone binds events to a view's `el` so let us have a look at that:

```
var print = Backbone.View.extend({
    el : $('ul li.newItem'),
    //...
```

When that `Backbone.View.extend` runs, there won't be any `li.newItem` elements in the DOM so you won't get a useful `el` in that view. The usual approach here would be to have a view that looks like this:

```
var Print = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'li',
    events: {
        'click': 'printText'
    },
    render: function() {
        this.$el.text('Hello world ' + this.options.i);
        return this;
    },
    printText: function(e){
        console.log($(e.target).text());
    }
});
```

We set `tagName` to `'li'` and let Backbone create the `<li>` by itself. Then we'd pass the counter value to the `Print` view as an argument, Backbone will take care of leaving the argument in `this.options.i` when we say `new Print({ i: ... })`.

Now we just have to adjust the `addItem` method in your `ListView` to create new `Print`s and add them to the `<ul>`:

```
addItem: function(){
    this.counter++;
    var v = new Print({ i: this.counter });
    this.$('ul').append(v.render().el);
}
```

Updated demo: http://jsbin.com/evoqef/10/edit

I've also made a few other changes:

1. Use [`this.$el`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-%24el) instead of `$(this.el)`, there's no need to create something that's already available.
2. Use [`this.$()`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-dollar) instead of `$('ul', this.el)`, same result but `this.$()` doesn't hide the context at the end of the `$()` function call and `this.$()` is more idiomatic in Backbone.

Comment: Question. I've always wondered this. When you `this.printText = _.bind(this.printText, this);` it binds the function `printText()` to the view object. So `this` inside of `printText()` represents the View. I actually never use `_.bind()`, but use `this` inside my view functions all the time. They all seem to point to the View object correctly. What is the purpose of doing the `_.bind()` in such a manner if `this` already points correctly?

Comment: @orangewarp: In general, `this` inside a function depends on how the function is called rather than how the function is defined. Consider the difference between `o.f()`, `f = o.f; f()`, and `f = o.f; f.call(x)`; all three are calling the same function but each one gives you a different `this` inside the function. There was some recent discussion of this over here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12241696/479863

Answer (score 0):

In your `_.bind(printText, this);`

The `printText` is outside of the scope of the init function. `this` as your second argument represents the print Backbone.View.

You could do something like this:

```
_.bind(this.printText, this);
```

and probably rid yourself of the `init()` error. But you could use `this` inside of printText and it will represent your View anyway.

```
printText: function() {
    console.log(this);  // this represents your view
}
```